# Can't find dependent libraries - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, oracle11g, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am having windows7 64bit installed in my machine.

- Oracle 11G client (32BIT)
- My eclipse 6.6(322bit)

While trying to establish connection from my Java app to Oracle 11G from my Eclipse it's throwing the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Tools\EMCO\Local Library Pack\bin\ocijdbc8.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
    at oracle.jdbc.oci8.OCIDBAccess.logon(OCIDBAccess.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:365)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:98)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:77)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:61)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getNewPoolConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:274)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:220)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:163)
    at com.cisco.emco.core.db.EMCOConnectionManager.getConnection(EMCOConnectionManager.java:99)
    at com.cisco.emco.mfgpln.recommitcp.gui.RCPUIP.pullORG(RCPUIP.java:595)
    at com.cisco.emco.mfgpln.recommitcp.gui.RCPUIP.printQueryScreen(RCPUIP.java:118)
    at com.cisco.emco.mfgpln.recommitcp.recommitcpp.run(recommitcpp.java:234)
    at com.cisco.emco.core.servlet.BaseServlet.doPost(BaseServlet.java:156)
    at com.cisco.emco.core.servlet.BaseServlet.doGet(BaseServlet.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at com.cisco.emco.systech.safe.authfilter.EMCOAuthFilter.doFilter(EMCOAuthFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:793)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:571)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use a pure Java type IV JDBC driver from Oracle.  It shouldn't need any native code.

I see Tomcat in the stack trace.  You should put the JDBC driver JAR in the Tomcat /lib folder before you start it up.

I see strange stuff in your stack trace: Oracle data pool, Cisco.  I don't know why you have those in your deployment.  I'd recommend just using vanilla JDBC and branching out once you have it working.

If you didn't even know about the JDBC JAR, I'd wonder what else you didn't know.  Could be anything wrong with this deployment.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: EMCO seems to be some internal (but webfacing) procurement application of Cisco. I wonder how happy they are that a contractor is posting this ;)

Comment: Good get there, Mark.  I can't speak for what Cisco needs.  The OP might be screwed until they learn about LD_LIBRARY_PATH and native code.